# Include 'normalize-scss' in Vue CLI 3

Tags: vue.js, sass, vue-cli, normalize-css

Just added the package `normalize-scss` to my new Vue project, but none of the styles are being applied... I've tried both:

`@import 'normalize-scss'` in my `styles.scss`

`import 'normalize-scss'` in my `main.js` page

Am I doing something wrong? The package is clearly there because the app runs, but it doesn't actually apply any css rules.

Comment: It seems there is not so simple: https://github.com/JohnAlbin/normalize-scss#how-to-use-it

Answer (score 8):

I figured it out. You need to put the `normalize()` after you import it, in your main.scss file. So:

```
@import 'normalize-scss';
@include normalize();
```

Answer (score 6):

after installing it with npm import it at the top of main.js file:

```
import "normalize.css"
```

Comment: In my case I had to use `import "~normalize.css"`

Answer (score 3):

If you have a main/global scss file you already use:

1. Add normalize.css (any of these) to your project: `yarn add normalize.css` (or npm)
2. in your main.scss for example: `@import '~normalize.css';`

Note the `~` for ambiguity as cli docs say: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#referencing-assets

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the correct way to do this but, if you are using vue-templates maybe you can try to import the style doing this:

```
<style lang="scss">
  @import 'src/assets/css/mycss_lib.css';
</style>
```

Also remember, do not use `scoped` in the style-tags. You also need, `scss loader` and `node-sass` to make this work.

Comment: This works for stylesheets that I've added manually, but not for this package.

Answer (score 0):

1. `npm install --save normalize-scss`
2. In main scss file `@import "normalize-scss/sass/normalize/import-now";`